# Automating keystore with keytool and openssl

Tags: bash, shell, ssl, openssl, keystore

I have this script:

```
PASSWORD=password123

openssl genrsa -out client2.key 2048
openssl req -new -key client2.key -out client2.csr -subj "/C=/ST=/L=/O=/OU=/CN=/emailAddress=" -passin pass:$PASSWORD -passout pass:$PASSWORD
openssl x509 -req -in client2.csr -CA ./ca/ca.crt -CAkey ./ca/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client2.crt -days 1825 -sha256
openssl pkcs12 -export -out bundle.p12 -in client2.crt -inkey client2.key -password pass:$PASSWORD
keytool -keystore truststore.jks -import -file ./ca/ca.crt -alias cacert -storepass $PASSWORD -keypass $PASSWORD -noprompt
keytool -destkeystore keystore.jks -importkeystore -srckeystore bundle.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass $PASSWORD -destkeypass $PASSWORD -deststorepass $PASSWORD -srckeypass $PASSWORD
```

The problem is with the last command, it returns:

> keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect

And don't understand why since the password is always the same for all of it.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Are you sure you aren't specifying `-alias 1`? On all versions back to 7 I get an error long before yours for `-srckeypass` without `-alias`. What version of Java (including update), and from where (Oracle, one of the OpenJDK distributors, a Linux packager, etc)? If your password isn't actually password123, does it contain any non-ASCII characters? If so, what kind of platform are you on, what shell, and with what locale settings? PS: it's _unnecessary_ to specify keypass when it's the same as storepass, as here, but it shouldn't be harmful and isn't for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While trying to manually run the import command, like this...

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore bundle.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 \
  -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass password123 \
  -srcstorepass password123
```

I received the following exception:

```
Importing keystore bundle.p12 to keystore.jks...
keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2159)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.loadSourceKeyStore(Main.java:2318)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1233)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:415)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:408)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: Empty subject DN not allowed in v1 certificate
```

That suggests that part of your problem may be that in your script
you're not providing any values for the subject. If I fix that:

```
openssl req -new -key client2.key -out client2.csr -subj "/CN=example-client" \
  -passin pass:$PASSWORD -passout pass:$PASSWORD
```

The manual import command works without a problem:

```
$ keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore bundle.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 \
  -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass password123 \
  -srcstorepass password123
Importing keystore bundle.p12 to keystore.jks...
Entry for alias 1 successfully imported.
Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled
[Storing keystore.jks]
```

But the command in your script -- which differs in that it includes
the `-srckeypass` and `-destkeypass` -- still fails:

```
Importing keystore bundle.p12 to keystore.jks...
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: if alias not specified, destalias and srckeypass must not be specified
```

If you remove the `-srckeypass` option from your script, it works as
expected.

Comment: Just one last question, if I wanted to leave CN empty (press enter when manually executed). What should I do in the command `openssl req -new -key client2...`

Comment: You can leave `CN` empty. You just have to provide a value for *some* part of the subject.